# Mocking the Service in Controller according to responce type

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I have a controller as below which has dependency to `customerService` which will return search `result` based on `listParam` from server:

```
  self.result = [];
  self.listParam= {};

  self.search= function () {
            self.result.length = 0;
            self.findingPromise = customerService.find(self.listParam);
            self.findingPromise
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.result = response.data.Result;
                }, function (response) {
                    var r = response;
                    ngNotify.set('Some problems occurred!',
                        {
                            type: 'error',
                            position: 'top',
                            sticky: true
                        });
                });
        };
```

I want to use *Jasmine* for **Unit Test**. I've read [Unit Testing for AngularJS](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/05/17/angularjs-testing-controller/) article. But I don't understand how I should use **mocking** in this case (search).  As you see, I may have resolved response or not based on service backend .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a spy to mock your service, maybe something like that would work

```
spyOn(customerService, "find").and.callFake(function() {
      return {
        then:function(callback) {
            var yourReturnObject = {};
            return callback(yourReturnObject);
        }
      };
    });
```

In addition, you can use a promise to make your service works or fail.

```
deferred = $q.defer();

spyOn(customerService, 'find').andReturn(deferred.promise);

// here your asserts


// In case that you want to make your service fail
deferred.reject({ ... });

// In case that you want to make your service work
deferred.resolve({ ... });
```

Comment: would you please give more information about how does it work? I can't understand how both type of response are managed and faked.

Comment: What do you want to test? A proper response from the server and a failing response from the server?

Comment: No, I don't want to test the service now. I want to test the controller operation. It will set the result for html page if the response was successfully got from service, and send an error notification if not. But I don't know the steps.

Comment: @Elnaz, please see my answer